# Is there a Japanese word for "finding the pleasantest point of an interior"?

Tags: words

I recently read a quote from architect Sverre Fehn that stated:

"Japan has a word for finding the pleasantest point in an interior..."

I was wondering if anyone might know what this word is.

Comment: This is a great question. Just like visiting the place you read about in a travel journal, statements about foreign languages always sound so fascinating right up to the point when you actually understand the language.

Comment: mmm... It's difficult. '味がある' comes to my mind. that is  慣用句.

Answer (score 2):

Best I can come up with is...
`趣きがある` `(おもむきがある)` `Omomuki` literally translates to 'Charming' on the internet. But that is too frank. It more means 'classy'.  If you are talking about a room, it means the place in the room that gives it it's charm.

For example:
`このはしらはおもむきがある` - this means 'this beam is charming' literally. But it means that the beam has a charming age that gives the room a good feeling.